# Any known jailbreak plugins causing containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier failure?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

My app is normal App Store app, not JB app. I saw a strange crash on one tester's JB iOS 7 device. From the crash logs I saw `[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]` throw exception for `nil` URL returned from `[NSFileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:]`. I guess it is because something distorted App entitlements or code signing which causes `[NSFileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:]` failure.

Are there any known plugins causing this kind of issues? Here is his plugin list: 
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My app had some crash for this bug. Now I just return nil path to avoid the crash.
One user told me he used the xcon plugin. And after he uninstall it, the app ran correctly.